# Converting\ joining a list into a float

Tags: list, join, floating-point, integer, decimal-point

by scraping a website I managed to get what i wanted, '2' '.' '7' '8'
I've put them in a list.
Now i want them all to be joined as a float 2.78

Can someone suggest something?

Thank You

I cannot join the decimal point to the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join them with `join()` function.

```
l=['2' '.' '7' '8']
float(''.join(l))

#output
2.78
```